# C++ Including header from another project in xcode 8

Tags: c++, xcode, include, xcode8, header-files

I'm using Xcode 8.2 on a mac, and I'm trying to include a header from another project. I made a quick example to use for this question as the one I'm working on is too large to post.

Here is the project I want to include:

```
#ifndef personType_hpp
#define personType_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class personType {

public:
    personType();
    personType(string, string);
    ~personType();
    void setName(string, string);
    string getFName();
    string getLname();
    void print() const;

private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

};

#endif /* personType_hpp */
```

and the .cpp for it is:

```
#include "personType.hpp"

personType::personType() {
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
}
personType::personType(string fn, string ln): firstName(fn), lastName(ln) {
}
personType::~personType() {
}

void personType::setName(string fn, string ln) {
    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
}
string personType::getFName() {
    return firstName;
}
string personType::getLname() {
    return lastName;
}
void personType::print() const {
    cout << firstName << " " << lastName;
}
```

Here is a simple file I made just to show the error I am receiving.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "personType.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
personType person1;
    person1.setName("bob", "smith");
    person1.print();
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
warning: skipping file '/Users/idontwanttogivemyname/Desktop/C++ Projects/malikBook/malikBookEx11_3/malikBookEx11_3/personType.hpp' (unexpected file type 'sourcecode.cpp.h' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "personType::setName(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "personType::personType()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "personType::~personType()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "personType::print() const", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The warning comes from me selecting the header file above (personType.hpp) in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section under the General tab (doing so allowed me to include the file in the main without Xcode complaining).

As a disclaimer: I have been googling this problem pretty extensively. It seems very basic as I'm sure many users need to access headers from other parts of their computer, but I haven't been able to find a solid answer for Xcode (within the past year...). Let me know if I need to provide any more info.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have successfully added the personType.cpp file to the compile list, but now using the same procedure, it says it cannot find the file in the big project I was working on. Here is a screenshot of the example project that it did work, followed by the one where it didn't. I don't see any reason why it would not include it in this one...

[Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scq4a.png)

[Not working...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwaV3.png)

the error i'm getting is simply:

```
/Users/idontwanttogivemyname/Desktop/C++ Projects/malikBook/malikBookGradeReportEx/malikBookGradeReportEx/studentType.hpp:15:10: 'personType.hpp' file not found
```

Comment: It seems that the `#include` is working fine. You are somehow not compiling or linking `personType.cpp`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`personType`'s methods can't be found anywhere. Yes, they are declared in the header, but the actual code for it can't be found. It's just like asking someone "there's this thing called plus" and then "what's 3 + 5?" without actually telling them how to add things together.

To add the code, you'll need to compile `personType.cpp`, and then compile `main.cpp` and link them together.

Try checking your build steps or project files in Xcode to make sure that both `main.cpp` and `personType.cpp` are compiled together.

Comment: Thank you! I went to the build phases tab and ensured the two .cpp files were included in the compile section. Such a simple fix, i knew it was something like that.

Comment: @LukeB No problem. If it worked, don't forget to mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Ah! i was looking for that button!

Comment: I actually have a new problem... I have added the personType.cpp file to my actual code in the same fashion as above but it says it cannot find the file period. I have a screenshot of the working example that was answered, and another screenshot of the non-working one. EDIT: I'm currently trying to post the images now...

Comment: @LukeB Is personType.hpp in the same directory as studentType.hpp? :)

Comment: No it is not! I'm pretty sure that must be the issue, but I thought including them in the compile sources would... include them? The studentType is in the project with the main function, and I'm calling the personType which is in the separate project.

Comment: @LukeB .hpp files are different from .cpp files. You "include" .hpp files, but you "compile" .cpp files. :)

Comment: Ok, that actually helps a lot. So I have the personType file compiling with the others, and I have included the personType.hpp in the studentType.hpp file as well as its cpp. I'm not sure what else it wants from me though.

Comment: @LukeB Have all the compile issues been fixed? :)

Comment: It seems so. There is only one error now: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue , 'personType.hpp' file not found. (in gray) studentType.hpp

Comment: @LukeB Are you sure you're using ```#include "personType.hpp"``` instead of ```#include <personType.hpp>```? :)

Comment: Yes, I've been googling around and checking other mistakes. What's interesting is that the class personType won't even show up in the main() function. I'm wondering if it has something to do with neither personType or studentType being "main" functions.

Comment: @LukeB This is getting a bit too long... You should create a new question. :)

Comment: I just found out I only had to go to file -> add files to ... -> add the cpp and the hpp file. Xcode puts them in their proper places... so that settles that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add copies of the files you want to #include into the project you are currently working on, to ensure that everything gets compiled *together* and linked *together* in the IDE.

At the moment, you are just referencing assets that were declared in a header, but have implementations in a .cpp file in the other project. The underlying code must be compiled and linked properly.